# How to own the object's monitor

Tags: java

I have some coding like this.

```
  public class WaitTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object object = new Object();
    try {
      synchronized (object) {
        object.wait(5000);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Does using **synchronized (object)** means WaitTest class is owning the monitor of object?

Comment: The main thread is the only one that owns `object`'s lock. The classes cannot own locks, the threads can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Classes don't own monitors, threads do.**

In your example, `WaitTest` doesn't own the monitor, the main thread does.

In particular, no other thread would be able to enter a `synchronized` block on the same object, including calling any of the `object`'s `synchronized` methods, if it had any such methods.

Comment: **using synchronized (object) means** that main thread is owning object monitor, isn't it?

Comment: @zvzdhk: Good catch, I didn't spot this subtle misunderstanding when reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

The thread owns the monitor, and there are three ways to own the monitor, according to the official JDK doc here: [Object.notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)

> A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.